# Stop duplication of inserted items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a object of items inside into a parent div. I select an item, it updates the object and then the object inserts into the page. However, this only appends to the parent div and not clear and re-insert (or even better, insert the latest item to the div).

So let's say I have this on my page as a list:

```
var selectedItemQueue = [
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key 1",
      "assetid":"92700754417_143965972",
      "amount":1,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA/"
   },
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key 2",
      "assetid":"92700754667_143865972",
      "amount":1,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA/"
   },
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Shadow Case Key 3",
      "assetid":"1293611210722_143865972",
      "amount": 2,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg/"
   }
];
```

And I selected a new item, which appends to the `selectedItemQueue` object.

```
var selectedItemQueue = [
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key 1",
      "assetid":"92700754417_143965972",
      "amount":1,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA/"
   },
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Chroma 2 Case Key 2",
      "assetid":"92700754667_143865972",
      "amount":1,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA/"
   },
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Shadow Case Key 3",
      "assetid":"1293611210722_143865972",
      "amount": 2,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg/"
   },
   {
      "market_hash_name":"Shadow Case Key 4",
      "assetid":"123393510722_143861972",
      "amount":1,
      "image":"https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg/"
   }
];
```

This is the code that pretty much handles the whole application:

```
// inserts items to page

function insertInventoryList(inventory, elem) {
    var elem = $(elem);
    for (var i = inventory.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var itemElem = itemTemplate(inventory[i].market_hash_name, inventory[i].assetid, inventory[i].image, inventory[i].amount);
        elem.append(itemElem);
    };
}

function itemTemplate(marketName, assetId, itemImage, itemAmount) {
    var template = 
        '<div class="inventory-item" title="' + marketName + '" data-item-id="' + assetId + '" data-amount="' + itemAmount + '">' +
            '<img class="inventory-item-image" src="' + itemImage + '" alt="' + marketName + '" width="95px" height="95px"> ' + 
        '</div>';
    return template;
}

function addItemToSelectedQueue(assetId){
    var itemObj = findItemById(assetId);
    var queueHasItem = false;
    for (var i = 0;  i < selectedItemQueue.length; i++) {
        if (selectedItemQueue[i].assetid === itemObj.assetid) {
            queueHasItem    = true;
            if (itemObj.amount > 1) {
                selectedItemQueue[i].amount++;
                console.log(inventory.assetid[itemObj.assetId].marketName);
            }
        }
    };
    if (!queueHasItem) {
        selectedItemQueue.push(itemObj);
        updateSelecteditems();
    } 
}

function updateSelecteditems() {
    insertInventoryList(selectedItemQueue, '#selected-items');
}
```

Right now this code just appends to the page, but adds to the variable correctly.

Now, there is one more thing that I'm trying to figure out that could solve my issue. Each child object has this key:

```
 "amount":1
```

The value can change, and I'd like to update this value in `selectedItemQueue` as well as the `data-amount` attribute on the item element. I thought that is some way related to fixing my problem but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any advice?

Thanks.

To clarify, I'm trying to insert a list of items into a parent element, the list is from an object, however when appending new items to the object, it also appends to the div, instead of just inserting the new item.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateSelecteditems() {
    $('#selected-items').empty();
    insertInventoryList(selectedItemQueue, '#selected-items');
}
```

Try this, it'll empty the DOM first, then re-add each one.

I will note however that your code will quickly become more difficult to manage when you mingle your presentation and data layers as you are here.

I would try to separate the concerns a bit here if I were you. Just my 2 cents though...if it's just a matter of getting it working quick, then code on my brother! :)

Comment: Could you give me a better example of "seperate the concerns"?

Comment: check this out : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery

Comment: keeping your Views  or UI components abstracted away from your data is essential to long term code stability and maintainability. Immagine how much of a pain it'll be if your inventory Item all of a sudden comes back with a list of other json elements? Say it had a reviews:[{reviewTitle:"Review 1", reviewText:"What an awesome inventory item", reviewRating:3}]

Adding that to your itemTemplate function becomes difficult.

Comment: I also like to try and create solid models with my results from any API. I'll make a  
              function Item(name, value, otherStuff){
                          this.name = name
                             ....   
                }

and try to represent my JSON as actual objects in code. It keeps it easier to handle long term.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep reading up on that! Do you have an answer to the end of the question (updating amounts in queue and view)